# Flutter : Ignore folders on final build

Tags: flutter

I am planning to create a scrips folder in my flutter project which will host some test scripts (like populate test items to the DB, etc.. )

I want it within the flutter project, so I can make use of existing model code and helper functions. But I do not want this folder to be part of the final build, as this can get bulky over time.

Is there a way to ignore a specific folder during build, so that its not part of the final build ?

I assume the test folder is not part of the final build, so I guess I can I put it there (or can I ? ), or is there a way to ignore a custom folder from the final build ?

Comment: have you solved this problem?